# How to copy text from InputField without adding spurious spaces?

Tags: bugs, inputfield

The problem happens when you copy text from an `InputField` and paste it into another: *Mathematica* inserts spaces in unnecessary places, such as around any `#` character.

For example, evaluate `InputField["aaaaa#BBB", String]`. Then select the contents of the `InputField`, copy it, and paste it over itself. The resulting test will be `aaaaa # BBB`, i.e. with an extra space immediately to the left and the right of the `#`.

It also happens with a `"` character, but in that case the extra space only appears on the left.

It's also worth noting that it *doesn't* happen when copying and pasting between literal strings, so it seems to be specific to the `InputField`.

How can this be avoided? Is it a bug? (I am using *Mathematica* 9, on Windows.)

Comment: Did you correctly set the second argument of `InputField`? This works for me: `InputField["", String]` in *Mathematica* 10.

Comment: Yes! I used InputField["", String].

Comment: OK, what version of Mathematica then? What operating system? Do you have another example? We need to figure out how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Wolfram Mathematica 9. Windows 7.
Sample:
InputField["aaaaa#BBB", String];
In field select "#BBB"; Copy;
Paste in end of line;
Result:"aaaaa#BBB# BBB"

Comment: I can reproduce this on MMA 9 Linux x64 but not MMA 10.

Comment: Confirmed this happens on both MMA9 and MMA10 on Win 7 for me, behaviour is slightly different on both.  Try copying "a#BBB"  on MMA9 you get "a # BBB" and on MMA10 you get "a #BBB".  Note that on MMA10 "#BBB" seems to paster ok.

Comment: a copy problem? Try `InputField["aaaaa#BBB", Boxes]`

Comment: I get no spaces if I paste the copied text between `""`. I get the same result as the OP if I copy the text between the quotes in `"aaaaa#BBB"` in a regular input cell and paste the result.  I'm not sure its a bug. *Mathematica* has had a funky, context-dependent way of pasting text for a long time.

Comment: I have this problem that extra spaces get inserted before symbols such as # or _ also when copying from normal output boxes. (Whether I copy as input or as plain text.) Does anyone know a work around?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a bug. I advise you to report this to Wolfram support, e.g. by using the "Give Feedback..." option on the Help menu or via their website.